# apt-get update updates all the packages?

Tags: apt

I am new  to ubuntu and would like to know if apt-get update updates the list of installed as well as uninstalled but available packages from  various repos?

Comment: sorry but didn't find the answer I was looking for. does available packages include the installed ones as well?

Comment: Available packages are those available in the repositories. You could have installed packages from anywhere, and they may or may not be in the repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, apt-get updates your full list of packages available in your added repo not just the ones that are installed.

Answer (score 4):

`apt-get update` just updates the list of available packages from the repositories configured in `/etc/apt/source.list` and `/etc/apt/source.list.d`.

It does not update any installed software packages, that's the job of `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: I understand that actual updating of packages happen when you upgrade , but in the list that you mentioned during update, does available packages include the already installed ones as well? like updating refreshes this list to  new versions( both available packages and installed ones) and upgrading/installing after updating actually installs these updated versions.

Comment: @samhitha ,yes when you install new packages from repository ,/etc/apt/source.list update and include new packages,But if your new package is not installed from repository you should add it to /etc/apt/source.list.d .