# Can I have more clarity re what update does?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

Here: [apt-get update updates all the packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886380/apt-get-update-updates-all-the-packages)
was a good question that IMO was neither a duplicate question nor sufficiently clearly answered...
So let me *guess* the answer & perhaps someone can confirm or not.
I suspect apt/apt-get update (a) reads (eg with dpkg --get-selections or --list) the list of installed items on the user's system, & then (b) conducts a search of the repo(s) the user has nominated in the 'sources' file(s) - looking for, & downloading the details of, just those items corresponding to list (a) where the repo has a more recent version. Of course, it would not be able to find items that were not *on* the repo eg where the user has installed from somewhere else.

Comment: `apt-get update` only updates your software lists, ie. packages that should be available and can be downloaded, are the latest etc.  It does NO upgrades of packages at all; as upgrade, full-upgrade & dist-upgrade do that role.  Yes `apt-get update` is limited to sources found in `/etc/apt/sources.list` & files within `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` but it does not upgrade any packages.  `apt-get update` also does not look at whatever packages you have installed; it's only touching software lists of what's available.

Comment: I'm aware it doesn't do any package *upgrades* but I had assumed it would only be able to generate a list of potential upgrades (or upgradable packages) by taking into account the packages (& their versions) that are currently *installed*.  Else, surely details of everything on the repo would need to be downloaded & the filtering would only occur when *upgrade* was executed. (which would seem inefficient)

Comment: It grabs software lists; so you can `apt install new-program` and it knows it's available too, ie. it isn't limited to whatever is pre-installed, and updates all software lists found in your sources.list files. `apt-get` doesn't look at any upgrades available, it doesn't care as it's not it's job.  `apt` however does look & provides notice of whatever upgrades are available (`apt update` still doesn't really take longer, as it can do multiple things in parallel better than `apt-get` did,  this extra task it performs shouldn't take longer - results however can vary)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @guiverc - looks like I guessed wrong about how this works.

Comment: If you're happy with my answer, you can accept it. You're most welcome to wait for a better explanation (if one comes) too...  *fyi: the unix philosophy was each tool does one job only, and does it really well.  Parts of GNU/Linux no longer really follow the unix one-job-well *philosophy* (*systemd* probably comes to mind) but parts do.

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get update` only updates your software lists, ie. packages that should be available and can be downloaded, are the latest etc. It does NO upgrades of packages at all; as `upgrade`, `full-upgrade` & `dist-upgrade` do that role.

Yes `apt-get update` is limited to sources found in `/etc/apt/sources.list` & files within `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` but it does not upgrade any packages. `apt-get update` also does not look at whatever packages you have installed; it's only touching software lists of what's available.

If you're using a badly outdated mirror; which can lead to package problems, it won't know or check for that (the output from the `apt-get update` can be useful to check https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors yourself for those problems).

From `man apt-get`

> ```
>    update
>        update is used to resynchronize the package index files from their sources. The indexes of available packages
>        are fetched from the location(s) specified in /etc/apt/sources.list. For example, when using a Debian archive,
>        this command retrieves and scans the Packages.gz files, so that information about new and updated packages is
>        available. An update should always be performed before an upgrade or dist-upgrade. Please be aware that the
>        overall progress meter will be incorrect as the size of the package files cannot be known in advance.
> ```

Note: This was copied from my 20.04 system, if you use `man apt-get` on your own box you'll see the reference manual page that perfectly matches your release.